# Extending Cypress.config with own properties using Typescript

Tags: typescript, testing, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I'm trying to extend Cypress config adding my own property in this way:

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('getUser', (originalFn: any) => {
    const overwriteOptions = {
        accountPath: `accounts/${options.accountPath}`,
    };

    return originalFn(overwriteOptions).then(response =>
        Cypress.config({
            authUserString: generateAuthUserString(response.email, response.password),
        })
    );
});
```

but I get this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(key: "url" | "browser" | "autoOpen" | "browserUrl" | "clientRoute" | "cypressEnv" | "isNewProject" | "isTextTerminal" | "morgan" | "parentTestsFolder" | "parentTestsFolderDisplay" | ... 84 more ... | "cypressBinaryRoot"): string | ... 16 more ... | { ...; }', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ authUserString: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '"url" | "browser" | "autoOpen" | "browserUrl" | "clientRoute" | "cypressEnv" | "isNewProject" | "isTextTerminal" | "morgan" | "parentTestsFolder" | "parentTestsFolderDisplay" | ... 84 more ... | "cypressBinaryRoot"'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(Object: TestConfigOverrides): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ authUserString: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TestConfigOverrides'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'authUserString' does not exist in type 'TestConfigOverrides'.ts(2769)
```

How can I add my own properties to the Cypress config? I am using Typescript.

Comment: Could you explain what's the purpose of this overwrite ?

Comment: Where is `cy.getUser()` coming from? Is there a package that adds this? AFAIK, base Cypress does not contain this function

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need to use `Cypress.config()` for this, you should instead use `Cypress.env()` which is freely extendable.

Adding items to config during the test has no effect, since none of the internal Cypress code knows about your custom property.

Therefore, you must be aiming to use it explicitly in your tests, for which `Cypress.env()` is the best choice.

The other problem is that  `Cypress.config({...})` would completely replace all existing config, even if it worked.

The correct syntax is to specify a key and value: `Cypress.config('key', value)`.

Same applies to `Cypress.env('key', value)`

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('getUser', (originalFn: any) => {
  const overwriteOptions = {
    accountPath: `accounts/${options.accountPath}`,
  };

  return originalFn(overwriteOptions).then(response =>
    Cypress.env('authUserString', generateAuthUserString(response.email, response.password))
    })
  );
})

it('uses authUser value', () => {
  cy.getUser({accountPath: 'admin'})
    .then(() => {
      expect(Cypress.env('authUserString')).to.eq('authorised')
    })
})
```